# Numbers or Letters for BodyPix - Person Segmentation in the Web Browser using TensorFlow.js

Tags: webcam, tensorflow.js

Running real-time person and body part segmentation in the browser using TensorFlow.js is excellent!

Link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix

How I can include numbers or letters for the different body parts segmentation instead of using different colors on the video overlay?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The api returns numbers for each bodypart: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix#example-usage-1

I'm not sure how you could draw these numbers on the screen as the resolution of each pixel is very small and you would not be able to see the numbers.

Comment: I'd like to draw the number on the centroid point of each bodypart so not on every pixel.

Is there any function that will return the list of pixel points corresponding to each bodypart segmentation so that I can compute the centroid?

I'd like to implement a function to return the centroid of the segmentation shape in the X and Y directions and then placed the number at that centroid point of each bodypart.